# Ionic equilibrium equation

Tags: equilibrium, aqueous-solution, solutions

What form is the ionic equalibrium equation? I have problem asking for it, but I'be done so many different equalibrium equations that I'm starting to get mixed up on which one is called what... Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ionic equilibrium equation is simply one that involves ions.

Example : $\ce {HA <=> H^+ + A^-}$